# Como hacer una consulta excluyendo datos que existen en otra tabla en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

mi problema es que tengo que hacer una consulta a una tabla la cual se llama acientos y sus atributos son:Id_aciento ,numero ,categoria ,Id_bagon(fk) y tengo otra tabla llamada boletos compuesta por Id_boleto ,fecha_reserva ,hora_reserva ,origen ,destino ,estado ,Id_cliente(fk) ,Id_aciento(fk) ,estas dos estan relacionadas de 1:M siendo Id_aciento el vinculo que las une , ahora bien lo que quiero es traer todos los acientos que tengan un boleto reservado y todos los acientos que NO tengan un boleto reservado
,con la primer consulta (traer todos los acientos que tienen un boleto reservado) no tuve problemas mi consulta fue asi:

```
select a.* from acientos a
inner join boletos b
on a.Id_aciento = b.Id_aciento
where b.estado = "Vigente"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al intentar traer lo acientos que no tenían un boleto reservado es donde no puedo lograr que me regrese resultados correctos ya que intente de esta forma:

```
select a.* from acientos a
inner join boletos b
on a.Id_aciento != b.Id_aciento
```

y de esta otra forma:

```
select * from acientos a
inner join (select a.* from acientos a
inner join boletos b
on a.Id_aciento = b.Id_aciento
where b.estado = "Vigente") ao
on a.Id_aciento != ao.Id_aciento;
```

pero no consigo que me retorne datos correctos ya que me regresa registros duplicados y registros con los acientos que se supone no me debe regresar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se puede apreciar me traer varias veces el asiento 1 cuando solo debe ser una ves y asi con los demas acientos dandome un total de 1000 registros siendo que yo solo tengo 240 acientos registrados en mi tabla acientos y mas adelante me trae por ejemplo el aciento con id 49 siendo que ese no me lo deberia de traer porque hay un boleto que esta relacionado con ese aciento.
espero puedan ayudarme gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Lo consegui estaba utilizando un inner join cuando en este tipo de consultas es preferente el uso de not exists comparto mi solucion por si alguien mas tiene la misma duda:

```
select a.* from acientos a
where not exists(select null from boletos b where a.Id_aciento = b.Id_aciento);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues a como luce tu pregunta, tomando tu primer consulta entonces deberías cambiar el uso de:

```
inner join
```

Por el de:

```
left join
```

Para que de esta forma considere:

- Las filas de la tabla de la izquierda *boletos* que existen al menos una vez relacionadas con algún registro de la tabla de la derecha que sería asientos
- También incluirá los registros o renglones de la tabla de la izquierda *boletos* cuya llave primaria no existe como llave foránea en algún renglón de la tabla de la derecha *asientos*

Propuesta

```
select a.* 
from acientos a
left join boletos b on a.Id_aciento = b.Id_aciento
where a.Id_bagon = NULL;
```

Comment: hola BetaM ya intente la consulta que me propusiste y me retorno los acientos que están vinculados con algun boleto no los que no están vinculados que son los que quiero que me regrese

Comment: prueba de nuevo @PepeToño